# How to set arbitrary delay between request and response in Netty?

Tags: java, http, netty

I'm implementing a primitive http server and I have a handler extending `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`. I have a method that's processing requests and I want to make a delay after processing specific request. How should I implement the pause so that server's behaviour still conforms to standards? I mean, client (browser etc.) should not behave like connection is lost or something like that, but just wait till the necessary amount of time passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use:

```
ctx.executor().schedule(...)
```

This way you could do the write in the Runnable you pass to the schedule call.

Comment: Once i use Scheduled events, i found that disconnect events are queued until the timer event executes. Is there are any relationship between timer events and IO events in netty ?